# update to database from local disk doesnt happen using pymysql

Tags: python, linux, bash, python-2.x

I have a scenario where I am downloading few .csv files from sftp server to my local linux server using python script(downloadsftp.py), once the files are downloaded I rename those csv files and trigger (updatedb.py), this whole thing cron jobs has been set up.

What I see is the files which I download from the SFTP server is updated but when the cron job runs automatically at specified time it does not push updated files to database but the old or previous files.
file permissions are chmod 777 for all files that are downloaded that is achieved via another cron job.

Here are my scripts :

downloadsftp.py

```
filelist = server.listdir()
for filename in filelist:
    filedate = re.search(".*\.csv$", filename)
    if filedate:
        print (filename)
        server.get("/sftpfolder/" + filename, "/opt/currentdata/" + filename)
        print("latest files downloaded to /opt/currentdata now proceeeding with creating backup")
        server.get("/sftpfolder/" + filename, "/opt/backupdata/" + filename)
        print("backup files created in /opt/backupdata")
        server.remove("/sftpfolder/" + filename)
        print ("cleaning files from FTP server")

print ("SFTP process completed closing FTP connection")
server.close()

print ("Bye Bye SFTP")

print ("Renaming files for updating database")
print(" ")

dir= "/opt/currentdata"

for newname in os.listdir(dir):
         if(newname.split('.')[0]=='CAS1' and "J" in newname):
                print newname,'BASD.csv'
                shutil.move(newname, "BASD.csv")

for newname in os.listdir(dir):
         if(newname.split('.')[0]=='LST' and "N" in newname):
                print newname,'CVGH.csv'
                shutil.move(newname, "CVGH.csv")
```

Dbupdate.py

```
def csv_to_mysql(load_sql, host, user, password):
    '''
    This function load a csv file to MySQL table according to
    the load_sql statement.
    '''
    try:
        con = pymysql.connect(host=host,
                                user=user,
                                password=password,
                                autocommit=True,
                                local_infile=1)
        print('Connected to DB: {}'.format(host))
        # Create cursor and execute Load SQL
        cursor = con.cursor()
        cursor.execute("truncate table mdb.data1;")
        cursor.execute("truncate table mdb.data2;")
        print("truncated old values from database...updating current values")
        cursor.execute(load_sql)
        cursor.execute(load_sql1)
        print('Succuessfully updated the table from currentdata dir')
        con.close()

    except Exception as e:
        print('Error: {}'.format(str(e)))
        sys.exit(1)

# Execution Example
load_sql = """ LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/opt/currentdata/BASD.csv' INTO TABLE mdb.data1\
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '"' IGNORE 1 LINES; """

load_sql1 = """ LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/opt/currentdata/CVGH.csv' INTO TABLE mdb.data2\
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '"' IGNORE 1 LINES; """

host = 'xxx'
user = 'dd'
password = 'ww'

csv_to_mysql(load_sql, host, user, password)
```

Cron jobs :

```
30 21 * * * cd /opt/currentdata/ && python /opt/currentdata/downloadsftp.py >> /opt/scriptlogs/sftp.log 2>&1
33 21 * * * cd /opt/currentdata/ && python /opt/currentdata/dbupdate.py >> /opt/scriptlogs/db1all.log 2>&1
```

I have no idea why the updated files are not pushed in database but the old files can somebody help here to understand if there is a problem with cron or downloading and moving the file in server because when I run the dbupdate.py script manually from the directory it updates correctly.

Comment: You'll need to share your `dbupdate.py` and the cron job definition with us as well. If you say, that downloading and renaming the files is confirmend to be working fine, then just showing that part of your process isn't enough, really :)

Comment: @shmee Sure, updated the same

Comment: @shmee problem is cron also runs at expected time, I have checked the logs and updates the Database but not with current files but the older ones.
Is it cached somewhere ?

Comment: No, I don't see any caching involved. Is it guaranteed that the download script has finished before the db updater runs? If the download loop takes longer than the three minutes between you script calls, then the db script still runs with the renamed files from the previous download.

Comment: As an aside, it seems you can combine the two `if` conditions for the file renaming into one loop over `os.listdir(dir)` in the `downloadsftp.py`.

Comment: @shmee Yes its guranteed that download of files happen within few secs so cron I have given atleast 2 mins difference

Comment: In all honesty, this looks to be either a timing issue or an environment issue (i.e. cron executes the scripts with a different user than you use when you call `dbupdate.py` manually). Unless there's an issue with what you did not share in `downloadsftp.py`, e.g. `server` is not defined in the code snipped above. But if both scripts are executed via cron and write their logs with all entries that are to expected on a successful run, then timing or env seem the only sources for this behavior to me.

Comment: @shmee might be environment issue, any idea how to resolve? and if there is a user issue as you say the files are having permission (chmod 777) still it should have user issue ?

Comment: Probably not. Since the download script seems to be able to read from and write to the destination directory when executed via cron there should be no issue for the same user to read the files for the DB update script. User/env issues indeed seem unlikely as well. Maybe add timestamps to your log prints? The remote server might be slower around 9:30pm than when you attempt the downloads manually.

Comment: @shmee Server is not slow when I manually execute the whole process downloading from sftp to local disk does not even take 1 min ...added timestamps and logs shows that it updates and script executes till end.....not sure where is the problem exactly and that too the data that is getting updated in database is not from recent past but very old most probably the first one when this script was run